# Check Mongodb MapReduce Support

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am new to MognoDB.
How I can check that my machine has support of Map-reduce or not?
The code of map-reduce is working on another machine but not at my machine.

Comment: All MongoDB servers support map-reduce.  In what way isn't it working?

Comment: Thanks! It means it has built in support of MapReduce. I should not enable it explicitly. My code is in Yii using extension I can't paste the as well. But it seems it dose not fill the collection using "out"

Comment: its just javascript functions running on mongo shell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map-reduce is just a procedure and not any specific service or library.
If you are doing basic query of mongoDB like...

```
> db.collectionname.find()
```

Than you can easily implement map-reduce code into the same shell...

Let me explain basic example from MongoDB cookbook.

assume your data documents(In sql rows) are like below.

```
> db.pageviews.find()

{
"url" : "http://example.com/photos",
"user_id" : ObjectID('4be1c916e031933119d78b30'),
"date": "Wed May 05 2010 15:37:58 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
}
```

This is a pageview document for any website.

The solution requires grouping the pageviews by day and then counting the total number of user visits and along with the number of unique visits for that day.

```
> map = function() {
  day = Date.UTC(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), this.date.getDate());

  emit({day: day, user_id: this.user_id}, {count: 1});
 }
```

your map will run like this on console..

```
> reduce = function(key, values) {
  var count = 0;

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    count += v['count'];
  });

  return {count: count};
}
```

your reduce will run like this...

and then

```
db.pageviews.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: pageview_results});
```

this is you basic map reduce...

Now when you query out collection pageview_results u will get reduced counts of mapped documents.

```
> db.pageview_results.find()
```